# Find the first instance of a variable in a .txt file and delete the line it is in

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I have created a text file that holds different names, followed by a number in the format:

```
Name 1, 10
Name 2, 5
Name 3, 5
Name 2, 7
Name 2, 6
Name 4, 8
ect.
```

I want to find the line that the variable 'Name 2' first appears on - so line 2, and then delete that line. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def skip_line_with(it, name):
    # Yield lines until find the line with `name`
    for line in it:
        if line.startswith(name):
            break  # Do not yield the line => skip the line
        yield line

    # Yield lines after the line
    for line in it:
        yield line

with open('a.txt') as fin, open('b.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(skip_line_with(fin, 'Name 2,'))
```

New file `b.txt` without unwanted line will be created.

---

**UPDATE** If you want to replace the file in-place (assuming file is not huge):

```
def skip_line_with(it, name):
    for line in it:
        if line.startswith(name):
            break
        yield line
    for line in it:
        yield line

with open('a.txt', 'r+') as f:
    replaced = list(skip_line_with(f, 'Name 2,'))
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(replaced)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a new file, so by overwriting the existing file?

Comment: @ABo, Why? Creating new file and move the new file to overwrite old file is not option?

Comment: @ABo, Or you can load all content into memory and write it back. But if file size if huge, it's not an option.

Comment: The file size won't be large. Also having a new file won't really work for what I want to achieve; as I want to be removing names multiple times.

Comment: I replaced the second to last line of code with: with open('a.txt') as fin, open('a.txt', 'r+') as fout: - The file a.txt is overwritten, but the last line is repeated do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @ABo, Your attempt does not work: open one file twice at the same time (for read/write) does not work.  I updated the answer to include another version that will overwrite existing file.